# Почему нет глагола "внемлить"?

Tags: этимология, словообразование, грамматика

Отчего возникает эта странная *л* у форм глагола *внимать*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Встречаются попытки вывести из "внемлю" инфинитив "*внЕмать*" (с ударением на первом слоге). Однако по Фасмеру этимологически начальной формой является слово со связанным корнем -ем- [**внемлю**], модификацией которого затем образован инфинитив "**внять"**:

http://oaji.net/articles/2015/1927-1432718243.pdf

> Связанный корень
>   -**ем**- / -ём- / -ним- / -ня- / -ым- / -’а- (праславянский *jьm) вычленяется в словах принимать, взять, объять, снять, разнять, внять,
>   приятель, приемлемо, **внемлю**, подъем, приемник и др. В словаре М.
>   Фасмера указано, что слово **внять**, например, образо- вано путем
>   *прибавления приставки к корню*: «*vъn- и *jęti» [Фасмер, 2003: Т. 1, с.
>   329]. Исходно протетический - н’- в праславянском языке появлялся в
>   положении после предлогов въ, къ, съ которые в праславянском языке
>   звучали *vъn, *kъп, *sъп. Тогда согласный корневой морфемы *j
>   сливался с конечным согласным предлога и происходило
>   переразложение основы. То же наблюдаем в слове взятка, образованного
>   из приставки *vъz и *jęti. Таким образом, этимологическая цепочка
>   данного связанного корня выглядит так: ***jьm → jęti → IАТИ → яти →
>   внять**, взять и др.

**P.S.** Этимологически родственные формы от "внять" (внял, внявший; церк. повел. "вонми", призыв "/давайте же/ вонмем") и от "внемлю" (внемли, внемлет, внемлющий) относятся к совершенному и несовершенному виду соответственно. Можно лишь предположить, что потребность распространения на несовершенный вид формы "внять" привела к инфинитиву "внимать", вариации которого со временем вытеснили из широкого употребления слова, родственные "внемлю", не имевшие "своего" инфинитива.

Comment: Интересно, а чьи это "попытки связать"? Кроме Aer'а и отчастb Sibylla? По-моему тут все настолько прозрачно с точки зрениея исторического делмения... Корень ИМ/Я (Иметь-взять). Другое дело, что в современном языке эта связь давно переосмысленна. Но все  равно, "внемать"- это нонсенс.

Comment: @IrinaGL я ничего не пытаюсь связать. Будьте внимательны. В большинстве словарей внемлит и др. - формы гл. *внимать*.

Answer (score 2):

О каком "наращении" речь? О звуке л на стыке корня и суффикса? Это переродившийся йот, он у многих глаголов есть. Спать - сплю. Сыпать - сыплю. Другое дело, что у внимать-внемлю парадигма несколько другая, тут что-то вроде супплетива, основы несколько разные у инфинитива и личных форм. Можно предположить, что форма "внемлеть" когда-то существовала, но устарела, из-за чего и появились парные формы внимаю-внемлю.

Добавлено.

**Aer предлагает считать корнем вним (внем).**

А это невозможно, нет такого чередования. Поэтому либо остается считать это разными корнями (как для школы), то есть супплетивом. При этом корень "внемл" возможен только с Л и, следовательно, Л - часть корня. Либо исходить их того, что написано у Фасмера (и не только у него, конечно), что корень ИМ/Я. Тогда Л - часть суффикса. В любом случае не наращение.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51895/discussion-on-answer-by-irinagl----).

Answer (score 2):

**Внимать** ― внимает (нейтр.) и **внемлет (книжн.), Л ― наращение** после губно-губных Б, П, М, сравнить: сыпать ― сыплю, сыплет.

**Пояснение**

**Грамота.Ру (Вопрос** № 254812)     Есть ли такое слово "приемлеть"? Какова его форма во множественном числе: "они не приемлют" или "они не приемлят"?
**Ответ** справочной службы русского языка: Такого слова нет. **Приемлю, приемлет ― книжные формы настоящего времени от принимать.** Правильно: они не приемлют.

Итак, принимать ― принимаю, принимает и приемлю, приемлет, внимать ― внимаю, внимает и внемлю, внемлет; отнимать ― отнимаю, отнимает и отъемлю, отъемлет (неотъемлемый).

Похожая история происходит со следующими  глаголами: мучить ― мучит и мучает, брызгать ― брызжет и брызгает, капать ― каплет и капает, двигать ― движет и двигает, метать ― мечет и метает и др. Эти глаголы имеют два варианта спряжения:  с **неусекаемой основой** (глагольный суффикс сохраняется) и с **усекаемой основой** (суффикс не сохраняется). **Различаются по стилю и оттенкам значений**.

Вн/им/а/ть ―  вн/им/а/ет, вн/емл/ет, здесь происходит усечение суффикса А, перегласовка ИМ/ЕМ в ударной позиции (?) и наращение Л после М.

Comment: Это не наращение. Выже сами пишети о глагольных суффиксах. Впрочем, и это не до конца правильно. Это не усечение, это фонетическаязаменв Й на Л.

Answer (score 1):

Потому, что есть пара ***внимать/внять***. Корень - тот же, что восходящее к германскому ***nemana*** и (пра?)индоевропейскому  **nem-***

Такая же основа (но с иной огласовкой) присутствует и в основах междометий ***ну!/на!*** (последнее следует различать от предлога).

Что касается согласного *эль*, то его появление типично для первого лица единственного числа настоящего времени и(ли) той же формы будущего совершенного после губных согласных (преимущественно у глаголов архаичного слоя).

Предполагаю, что он развился из неслогового -у- который, возможно, был некогда частью "юсообразного" дифтонга.

К такой же парадигме относятся:

*терпеть, вопить, теребить, крепить, кропить,* -*цепить, спать, любить*

Полагаю, список можно дополнять.